# Linq2XML separate keys into List

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to read a config.xml and put each item into a combobox so that the XML file is the datasource. This is my code, which only gives me one entry in my combobox. How do I separate the keys? This is my filter:

C#

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(configfile);
var anredeItems = from key in xmlDocument.Descendants("Anrede")
                  select key.Value.Trim();
anredeNrComboBox.DataSource = anredeItems.ToList();
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config>
    <Anrede>
        <key_1>Herrn</key_1>
        <key_2>Frau</key_2>
        <key_3>Herrn Dr.</key_3>
        <key_4>Frau Dr.</key_4>
        <key_5>Herrn Dr. Med.</key_5>
    </Anrede>
</Config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Descendants("Anrede")` query will get you the element `Andrede`, and reading the `Value` property of that will return the concatenation of all descendant text nodes, which is what you are seeing in your combo box.

What you want are each of its child element values:

```
var items - doc.Descendants("Anrede")
    .Elements()
    .Select(x => x.Value.Trim())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code like this:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(configfile);
var anredeItems = xmlDocument.Root.Elements("Anrede").Elements().Select(p => p.Value.Trim());
anredeNrComboBox.DataSource = anredeItems.ToList();
```